# Какое ПО использует обнаружение ВПО с помощью семантики?

Tags: безопасность, вирусы, семантика

Здравствуйте!

Я пишу курсовую работу на тему обнаружения ВПО с помощью семантики.
С теорией мне в целом все понятно, осталось небольшая часть, в которой преподаватель сказал посмотреть и проанализировать существующие программные средства, которые используются для обнаружения вредоносного  ПО с учетом семантики.

Ума приложить не могу, на что стоит обратить внимание... На какие конкретно программные средства. Подкиньте идей, пожалуйста :)

Comment: @IceFox, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Введи в яндексе: антивирус

**Обновление**

Я предложил вам направление, где семантический поиск ВПО используется очень широко. Преподаватель вам ясно дал понять что нужно делать. Надо посмотреть и проанализировать существующее ПО. Нужна конретика? Возьмите антивирус Касперского и DrWeb, например. В обоих используется семантический поиск. В остальных тоже, я почти уверен, используется, но эти просто на слуху.

Comment: @Get,
=_=
мне нужен упор на семантику...
и больше конкретики, чем "антивирус"... Или Вы мне предлагаете определение почитать?

Comment: Я предложил вам направление, где семантический поиск ВПО используется очень широко. Преподаватель вам ясно дал понять что нужно делать. Надо посмотреть и проанализировать существующее ПО. Нужна конретика? Возьмите антивирус Касперского и DrWeb, например. В обоих используется семантический поиск. В остальных тоже, я почти уверен, используется, но эти просто на слуху.

Comment: @Get, спасибо) Так намного понятнее, что Вы хотели сказать! :)

Comment: @Get, не могу найти информацию по семантическому поиску в статьях по Касперскому и Доктору Вебу... Не могли бы Вы скинуть ссылку, откуда эта информация?

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения семантики, не вполне ясно, что же есть на самом деле *вред* и что есть вредоносное ПО. Операционная система, которая оставляет лазейки для посторонних подглядывать за вашими письмами, кредитками, звонками и местонахождением? Затягивающая игра, которая требует платы за экаунт, и «заставляет» вас фармить вместо того, чтобы готовится к экзамену? Браузер, через который вы сидите в социальной сети и прокрастинируете? Больше ли вреда от того, что комп стал частью ботнета из-за неумелости юзера или частью проекта SETI@home из-за излишней его доброты?

Comment: О_о
Не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду О_о

Comment: Ну, если мы говорим о семантике: нужно понять _определение_ вредоносного ПО, а значит, понять _определение_ вреда. Если «вирус» развлекает вас интересными картинками и добавляет денег вам на кредитку (даже не спрашивая вас), а взамен лишь занимает 5 килобайт на вашем винте — можно ли считать его вредоносным ПО?

Comment: @VladD, это уже философский вопрос)

Что имеется ввиду в рамках учебного задания под вредоносным ПО то понятно :)

Comment: @IceFox: А любой вопрос о семантике граничит с философией. Семантическое определение есть определение по вредоносным действиям. Для определения того, вредоносно ли действие, мы неизбежно упираемся в вопрос того, что такое вредоносное действие.

Антивирусы используют _эвристики_: подменяет системные файлы — значит, наверное, вирус. Но обновление системы тоже подменяет системные файлы, так что приходится дописывать ad hoc-правило: «но система не считается вирусом». С другой стороны, как определить, что есть система, а что только притворяется ею?

---
Так что не очень понятно на самом деле.

Comment: Точно. 

"Что кошке хорошо -- мышам смерть".

Comment: @VladD, не, Вы конечно очень интересно рассуждаете :DD

Но ведь довольно понятно, что от меня требуют в работе :D

Тут я как раз просто хочу найти источники, где можно узнать про приминение семантики в конкретных программах(хоть как-то связанными с уязвимостями, вирусами).

Comment: @IceFox: В том-то и дело, что вопрос с семантикой сложен, так что у антивирусов в основном чистый «синтаксис». Они не «понимают», что делает программа, они тупо применяют несколько готовых шаблонных правил. (Хотя, почитайте про [парадокс китайской комнаты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) насчёт отличия семантики от синтаксиса).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо! Прочитала, довольно интересно, а главное доступно описано. Наверное, я даже упомяну об этом где-нибудь в приложениях курсовой :)

Comment: @VladD, да, очень интересно.

Правда, я слышал (от одного весьма толкового человека) и такое высказывание -- "если долго вглядываться в текст на незнакомом языке, то постепенно его смысл начинает доходить до тебя".

Но, к компьютерам (я думаю) это не относится (по крайней мере пока еще не относится).

Comment: @avp: Этот же принцип, наверное, применим и к программированию: если программировать на каком-то языке [10 лет](http://www.williamspublishing.com/21-days.html), то даже не особенно задумываясь, постигаешь его суть.